# Are diplobacillus physically connected?

Tags: bacteriology, taxonomy

I know that a diplobacillus is a bacillus bacteria that has a buddy 'attached' to it.

What I haven't been able to determine is exactly how is it 'attached'? Are their cell membranes fused - are they even touching? If they aren't fused, what keeps them together? Also, does this make diplobacillus a multi cellular organism because there are multiple cells in this organism?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything about diplobacilli, but I did find some information on *Streptococcus pneumoniae*, which has been extensively studied. *S pneumoniae* (R6 strain) normally occurs as diplococci. Electron micrographs—see [here](https://jb.asm.org/content/jb/172/11/6499.full.pdf) and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC217837/pdf/jbacter00244-0434.pdf)—show that the two cocci of a pair share a portion of cell wall. This is a result of incomplete separation during cell division. Also, mutations in peptidoglycan-hydrolysing enzymes [have been shown](https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/32/2/345/2684022) to produce longer chains of cocci.

Presumably, something similar holds for diplobacilli.

Calling these bacteria 'multicellular' might be inappropriate, because [multicellularity implies at least some division of labour](https://www.ck12.org/book/ck-12-biology-advanced-concepts/section/3.24/): the cells perform different functions in a cooperative manner. Diplobacilli (such as [*Moraxella lacunata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morax-Axenfeld_diplobacilli)) or diplococci have not been shown to have such a division of labour, as far as I know.